# How can I run telnet command in the python GUI?

Tags: python

How can I run telnet command in the python GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), though it may be too low-level for what you want.